# Send the stdout of spawnSync to another spawnSync stdin

Tags: node.js, stdio

How do I emulate linux's | (pipe) in a node.js app to pipe the `stdout` of a command to the `stdin` of the next command. Both commands are being spawned with `spawnSync`.

This (pseudo code) works as expected in the commandline:

```
$ command1 -arg1 file | command2 arg2
> someoutput
```

But this does not:

```
const spawnSync = require('child_process').spawnSync;

const c1Spawn = spawnSync('command1', ['arg1', 'file']);
const c2Spawn = spawnSync('command2', ['arg2'], { input: c1Spawn.output });

const someoutput = c2Spawn.output;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found the answer by using `input: c1Spawn.stdout` instead of output as the in for the second command.

```
const spawnSync = require('child_process').spawnSync;

const c1Spawn = spawnSync('command1', ['arg1', 'file']);
const c2Spawn = spawnSync('command2', ['arg2'], { input: c1Spawn.stdout });

const someoutput = c2Spawn.output;
```